# Wasn't this better suited for server fault?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11850640

I marked it as belonging on server fault. I failed the audit and penalized 7 days? Was I completely wrong in thinking it would better fit there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were confused by the Linux tag. Redis is a data store that involves programming to add/retrieve data.

Server Fault is more about server administration. He's not trying to setup/maintain Linux. He's trying to checksum file data into Redis.

Comment: redis is absolutely not a programming language.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Clarified